# How can I ventilate an underground garage to make it safe to work from?

Tags: basement, air-conditioning, garage, air-quality

I live in a townhouse. We have an attached garage which is underground and with no windows. it gets air by either the attached stairways which leads home or by the garage door which leads to the shared garage entry and gate.

I would like to work there for a few hours a day.

What would be the best way to ventilate the garage? I'm not concerned by temperature, only by not breathing unhealthy air. Hopefully I can get fresh air, but I'd settle for filtered air as well.
Another criteria is I don't want to have a very loud device.

thank you!

Comment: Maybe open the garage door a few inches and use a small fan under the door to circulate?   Depending upon outdoor temps, this may or may not be a good idea!

Comment: The simplest is just open the garage door.

Comment: What are the radon levels?

Answer (score 3):

Keep the garage door open and get one or two ventilation fans      to circulate the air. See picture below from Amazon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Passive or Active solution**

Passive would be absolutely silent (no noise)

You would install tilting Garage door windows, probably with tinted glass for privacy.

**Active solution**

It is nosy, but delivers forced air exchange.

You need 2 Fans one for intake one for return.
Now partially open the garage door and let it run.